# How to add Banner ads in Android View Pager

Tags: android

In Android I have tried to place the google Banner ads inside the Viewpager. I can Succesfully place the ads, but if I give padding for banneradview it is not displaying.

How to set padding for the adviews? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: do not give padding or margin to original adview else it will trow an error so keep as it is it will automatically adjust as per screen

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. but i need space between two bannerads

Comment: then add an extra view between it as a space but dont use margin or paddin parameter in adview or in its parent layout else it will not show ad even it will not run the code too i suffered from such kind of problem :(

Comment: hi if i left like that it is streched to the next ads in the view pager.. do i need to do any thing with off screen page limit ?

Comment: ur showing ad in vertical format ?
i mean u want to show 2 advies in vertical direction one after other in second line with some distance? is it?

Comment: Nope its Horizontal..

Comment: Every item is not an Adview one is image view another one is add and likewise.. When i use image view i am doing like fit scale xy and centercrop it is fine ... adview creates the prob

Comment: then take one linear layout with horizontal orientation and keep it in scroll view and keep your adview as per your requirement i would like to say you just try it see what happen may it work for you